# Why do my friends get Tough Break contracts every 15 minutes and I don't?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I've had the campaign pass for a while now and I'm on about 15/26 contracts with the Tough Break campaign pass.

I get 2 contracts per week, as it says here: [When do I get new Contracts on the Team Fortress Tough Break Update?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248562/when-do-i-get-new-contracts-on-the-team-fortress-tough-break-update) but my friends who got it yesterday are getting a contract as soon as they complete the previous one, and are now on 25/26 contracts. Considering I've had the campaign pass since early December, What the hell? The contracts page is blank most the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract system appears to occasionally bug out and give people a bunch more contracts than they should get.

There are only supposed to be 15 (maybe 16) as of January 29, 2016 (i.e. today).

Edit: All 26 contracts should be available as of March 9 or so.

Answer (score 1):

**How many total contracts have they completed so far?**

Your say your friends have only just bought their campaign pass, then they will receive new ones **as they complete their current ones** until they are **equal** with everyone else, which as Powerlord states is ~15-16 contracts as of January 29, 2016.

The contract system is built this way so that people who buy in late, or are unable to complete their contracts within a week, won't miss completing any contracts (and therefore not earning drops).

It also means that if you are lagging behind in completing your current contracts, and miss the day where you will normally be awarded the contract, you will get new ones straight after you finish them as well.

Comment: No, there really is a bug right now where people may continuously get contracts until they get all 26.  It's been talked about several times on Reddit with screenshots to show that it's really happening.

Comment: @Powerlord - Yeah I just found the threads and have been reading them, I've removed my comment